# Сработает ли тест в Django?

Tags: python, django

Добрый день! Пытаюсь написать тест на оставление комментария. Правильно ли я его написал, и что не так? Как будет правильно? Подскажите неуЧу.

Сам тест:

```
class CommentAddTest(self):

    def test_add_comment(self):
        client = Client()
        comment = CommentForm(yourname='Alex', email='alex@sobaka.ru', message='Lorem Ipsum Doloren Ipsum...', enable=True)
        comment.save()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Моделька:

```
class CommentForm(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Комментарии'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Комментарий'

    yourname = models.CharField(max_length=124, verbose_name=u'Ваше имя:')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=u'Ваш email:')
    message = RichTextField(verbose_name=u'Текст комментария:')
    article_id = models.ForeignKey(Posts)
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Комментарий к %s" %self.article_id.title
```

После запуска выдает следующую ошибку:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: blog.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 428, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 369, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/kelevra/uroki/django/mysite/blog/tests.py", line 18, in <module>
    class CommentAddTest(self):
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Сами комменты оставляются через форму, или правильней будет её тестировать? Или как?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь класс `CommentAddTest` наследовать от некого `self`. Подозреваю, что там должно быть `CommentAddTest(TestCase)`

Comment: Всё верно, только джанговский класс для юнит-тестов.

Comment: Теперь пишет `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: comments_commentform.article_id_id`   Если я передаю в тесте ` comment = CommentForm(yourname='Alex', email='alex@sobaka.ru', message='Lorem Ipsum Doloren Ipsum...', article_id = 1, enable=True)` Пишет `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "CommentForm.article_id" must be a "Posts" instance.`